# Trying to build GAE PHP runtime extension

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

I'm trying to build GAE PHP runtime extension for local development.
I've followed instructions described in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-extension

When running the .configure i get the following error:

*configure: error: Invalid protobuf include path /home/sergio/Workspace/appengine-php-extension*

The configure command:

*./configure --enable-gae --with-protobuf_inc=/home/sergio/Workspace/appengine-php-extension --with-protobuf_lib=/home/sergio/Workspace/appengine-php-extension*

**/home/sergio/Workspace/appengine-php-extension** is the absolut path to the headers and libraries created on the second step of the instructions:

> Set  and  to the absolute path to the protobuf headers and libraries installed in the previous step, usually /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib.

I've tryed to use /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib. Didn't work either. Does any one know what I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

For your proyect is absoluty necesary custom appengine-php-extension. You could use app-engine-php by default.

Only download google cloud sdk: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/?hl=es

And after install the php extension:

`gcloud components install app-engine-php`